# fetch returning "true" instead of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am working on a private project and when i sent a PATCH request to the back end and console.log the data in the front end instead of returning the updated user data it just sent back 'true', so when i try the setstate on some thing i can't bc i get back 'true'. am i doing smth wrong?

i was expecting to recieve the updated datas but i just got back "true"

this is my fetch

```
const updateUser = (e, updateP, navigate, setUpdateP, user) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (user.key.length <= 40) {
            fetch(`/users/${user.id}`, {
                method: "PATCH",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(updateP)
            })
            .then(resp => {
                if (resp.status === 202) {
                    resp.json().then( data => {
                        console.log(data)
                        // setUpdateP({
                        //     name: user.name,
                        //     email: user.email,
                        //     key_words: user.key,
                        // })
                        navigate('/profile')
                    })
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log('key word cannot reach beyond 40 characters')
        }
    }
```

and this is my method that handles the update

```
def update
      updated_user = @user.update!(user_params)
      render json: updated_user, status: :accepted
    end
```

Comment: If you just get back `true` (like when you do the `console.log`) it's a back end issue. Since the back end looks like Rails, and you're calling `update!`, this makes sense: `update!` calls `save!`, which returns `true` unless there's an error.

Comment: Get in the habit of reading the documentation for API methods. Read what `update!` returns in Rails.

Comment: Look into using your browser dev tools to view the response of the update. My guess is that the update function on the backend returns a true/false value to indicate if the action was successful or not

Comment: FWIW: the first thing I would have done is checked the network tab: if the response wasn't what I expected I'd look at the back end. A sanity check of `updated_user` via logging, debugger, pry/byebug, or running an `update!` in the Rails console would show me that my assumptions were incorrect and I needed to read the docs.